# Android - item and subItem from resources

Tags: android, android-layout

I've faced a problem by adding a question for my questionnaire from res/values.
As I need a ListView followed by checkbox in each line, I've created a custom ListView.
This is my list_item.xml

I've deleted android:text="@string/textLarge" and "@string/textSmall" lines, that's why it has an empty line in TextView tags.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView_large"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="16sp">
</TextView>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView_small"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="12sp">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:gravity="right">
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBxc">

    </CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and a simple list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
```

my Main.java file is next

```
 public class Main extends ListActivity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, R.id.textView_large,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions)));
}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] strings) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)          getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.questions);
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBxc);
        TextView txtLarge = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_large);

        TextView txtSmall = (TextView)  row.findViewById(R.id.textView_small);

        txtLarge.setText(items[position]);
        return row;
```

and it works correctly if I add an item from questions.xml, but it displays only 1 line, however I need to make a question as an item (i.e "Do you do some sports?") and some comment below (i.e "Check it if you do"). How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom ArrayAdapter (a class that extends from ArrayAdapter) and set it for your list-view `listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter)`
In this adapter you have to override the getView method (to return your custom list-item-view).

See also this example:
http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/03/customized-listview-items-selection.html

Comment: thanks to Marc, but I've solved it in a little bit different way

Answer (score 1):

This piece:

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
```

is not good: you create new item view always, even if it already exists destroying excessive objects costs time. And you can use functionality of the ArrayAdapter itself. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532548/715269).